# asp mvc iis7 debug mode errors page outputs unreadable characters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7, stack-trace

I'm running an asp.mvc web application on localhost on iis7 (win7) and I don't get my normal yellow screen of death with the call stack. I always get a page full of random unreadable characters. Has anyone ever seen this? How do I get my callstack back?

[image: Error Stack Characters]

Comment: I have seen this when the HTTP Response is not flushed or ended correctly. Are you doing anything like Response.End or Response.Flush in your controller? Can you post some code for the controller.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might find the [following blog post](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2011/May/02/ASPNET-GZip-Encoding-Caveats) useful. You are probably using gzip.